Which packages should be installed system-wide with pip when using pipenv?
I'm using pipenv to manage virtual environments for my Python projects. I currently have the following packages installed system-wide using pip:
certifi==2024.8.30
distlib==0.3.8
filelock==3.16.1
pipenv==2024.0.2
platformdirs==4.3.6
setuptools==75.1.0
virtualenv==20.26.5

I was wondering if all these packages are necessary system-wide. I understand pipenv and virtualenv are, but are the others not needed?

pipenv pulls in setuptools, virtualenv, certifi. virtualenv pulls in distlib, filelock,  and platformdirs

You can use python -m pip show pipenv, it will tell you pipenv's dependencies, then you can check each dependency if it has dependencies of its own.
